# Postgres 12 - how to reduce size of wal-directory

Tags: postgresql

I have upgraded postgres 9 to 12 with pgdump and restore it to new database. All seems to be ok. Afterwards I noticed, that size of ../12/main/ has grown a lot and most of it is in pg_wal-directory.
Size of ./base is 27GB and size of ./pg_wal is 61GB. On postgres 9 values were 31GB / 1GB (pg_xlog).

After some checking, postgres.conf-file shows default values as:

```
# max_wal_size = 64GB 
min_wal_size = 5GB
```

I change value of max_wal_size to 4GB and removed comment

```
SHOW ALL;
```

told

```
max_wal_size | 4GB
```

But size of pg_wal stays on 61GB.
Is there some other parameter, I should change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value is 1GB – you must be using a modified version of PostgreSQL.

I would first check `pg_stat_archiver` and the log file if there are problems archiving WAL segments. Then I would check for stale replication slots. Finally, I would check the setting of `wal_keep_segments`.

If all three don't account for the size, you just have to wait: WAL segments are removed at every checkpoint. The more activity there is, the faster WAL segments will get filled and deleted.

Comment: Thank's. You are right, I 'm using modified config-file, where default is 64.
My archiver is off and `pg_stat_archiver`returns
archived_count = 0 and stats_reset = 2020-08-19 11:55:39.775666+00
Nothing at log-files and no replication in use.
`wal_keep_segments = 250`

Comment: If your WAL segment size are the default 16MB, 250 segments would be 4GB. Wait a bit and see if things improve over time.

Comment: My wal_segment_size=1GB (default for this modification - maybe). Let's see, what will happened.

Comment: Then don't hold your breath. Your WAL directory will grow to 250GB (250 segments of 1GB each). Reduce `wal_keep_segments` or increase your disk space.

Comment: Fortunately disk is cheap :-) Maybe it's wise to recreate db with modified settings.

Comment: Solved! error where on customized initdb-script --wal-segsize=1024 
Some reason, value where 1GB. When I changed it to 16 and recreate database, size has been solved. Now whole 12/main-directory is 44GB. Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Following on from jjanes' answer ...

If you have a server with very low traffic, a development server for example, have done something like a data import which generates a lot of writes, and so have a large number of wal segment files, the amount of storage consumed by wal segments may grow up to `max_wal_size`. If you reduce `max_wal_size` in the server config, the actual number of wal segment files won't drop until the server cycles through those old files.

Here's a function which will force the server to cycle through all of the existing segment files. It does this by repeatedly calling `pg_switch_wal()` to switch to a new wal segment and then checkpoint to force writing a checkpoint on the new wal segment.

In the scenario described this will trigger postgres to reduce the number of segment files down to the current `max_wal_size` and possibly below.

This may be counterproductive on a live server, particularly if you are doing wal archiving, so please only use this if your situation matches the description above.

Depending on how many wal segments you have, this may take some time to complete.

```
create or replace function pg_wal_cycle_all() 
returns int language plpgsql 
as $$
declare
    wal_count int;
    wal_seg varchar;
begin 
    select count(*) - 1 
    into wal_count 
    from pg_ls_dir('pg_wal');

    for wal in 1..wal_count loop 
        select pg_walfile_name(pg_switch_wal()) into wal_seg;
        raise notice 'segment %', wal_seg;
        checkpoint;
    end loop;
    return wal_count;
end;$$;
```

Execute with:

```
select pg_wal_cycle_all();
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like at some point, the server must have actually been running with `max_wal_size = 64GB`, probably during the initial import.  If it were undergoing intense activity, it could have recycled most of the wal files for future use, thinking it will need them very soon based on high recent activity.  Once recycled, the files are never removed until after they are used.  If the server has low activity once the initial import is done, it could take a very long time to use that amount of WAL files.  You could check to see how many of the files are recycled for future use by a query like this:

```
select count(*) as all, 
    count(*) filter (where filename > pg_walfile_name(pg_current_wal_lsn())) as future 
from pg_ls_dir('pg_wal') as t(filename);
```

If you are desperate to get that space back, you could very very carefully delete the files with names which are the furthest in the future.  Deleting the wrong ones though would thoroughly destroy your database.  If you don't really need the space, it is safest to just let them alone, and they will slowly be re-used and deleted naturally over time.

Comment: sql returns, in my case, all = 61 and future=1.
This db is copy of production to development, so it can easily delete and recreate again. Very low activity